# execute shell code interactively in python

Tags: python, console

I call pdflatex from python using

```
executeCode = 'pdflatex -shell-escape "' + packageName + '.tex"'
result = os.system(executeCode)
```

The LaTeX document can however have an error, in which case pdflatex ask for keyboard input.
For python this is the same as an endless loop. Within PyScripter I can not even stop python. I have to kill pdflatex.

Now I need two things
1. I want to see the output of pdflatex
2. I need to interact with pdflatex on the console

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `--interaction nonstopmode` option pdflatex won't stop and ask for input.

Using the `subprocess` module gives you more options about how to handle the process.

```
subprocess.call(['pdflatex', '--interaction', 'nonstopmode', '-shell-escape', packageName + '.tex'])
```

You can use the `stdout` and `stderr` options to redirect those outputs to a pipe or to a file.

If you want to capture the program's output, use `subprocess.check_output()` instead.